# iOS Firebase messaging not receiving

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been breaking my head on this today and yesterday, for some reason my iOS application is not receiving any firebase notifications. For as far as I know I have done everything as it should be.

- I have checked the certifications in my Apple developer account and everything is set up correctly (see screenshots).
- I am testing on a physical device
- Firebase is set up properly and the logs show it connected to firebase correctly
- I have enabled push notifications, background fetch and remote notifications in the capabilities tab of the project
- I have added my APN key from my Apple console to Firebase

When sending a notification through the Firebase console to a topic or to all iOS apps nothing happens. I have the same app running on android smoothly which is receiving all notifications when targeted.

AppDelegate.swift

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  CoyoteBreda
//
//  Created by Milan van Dijck on 28/02/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Miscoria web development. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB2JNmY2D6q7lYKmJmyeeDXdk-ILEM4q1Q")
        UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

        //Initialize firebase
        //FIRApp.configure()

        do {
            Network.reachability = try Reachability(hostname: "www.google.com")
            do {
                try Network.reachability?.start()
            } catch let error as Network.Error {
                print(error)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                         name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // -----------------------
        // FIREBASE MESSAGING
        // -----------------------
        FIRApp.configure()

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        requestNotificationAuthorization(application: application)

        if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
            NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for iOS9: \(userInfo)")
            //TODO: Handle background notification
        }


        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true;
    }

    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }
        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
    {
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
    }

    func connectToFcm()
    {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("[Unable to connect with FCM. \(String(describing: error))]")
            }
            else
            {
                print("[Connected to FCM.]")
            }
        }
    }

    var applicationStateString: String {
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            return "active"
        } else if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
            return "background"
        }else {
            return "inactive"
        }
    }

    func requestNotificationAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("[REGISTERING FOR TOPICS]")
        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/activiteit")
        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/message")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        // Update the database
        DatabaseUpdater.performUpdate(performFetchWithCompletionHandler: completionHandler)

        // TODO: update views

        //completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        connectToFcm()

        DatabaseUpdater.performUpdate(performFetchWithCompletionHandler: {(result: UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void in
            NSLog("Done updating!")
        })
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }


}

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // iOS10+, called when presenting notification in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) willPresentNotification: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    // iOS10+, called when received response (default open, dismiss or custom action) for a notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveResponse: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle background notification
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Application output:
[image: Application output]

Apple certificates:

[image: Provisioning profile]

[image: Provisioning profile selection]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which "FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType" you are using .? with which certificates?  means  Developer or Distribution?

Comment: @VarinderSingh `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)` so i am using `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox` I am using a iOS Development provisioning profile with an iOS Development certificate.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseMessaging
 import UserNotifications

 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //create the notificationCenter







    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        //FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }







    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    print("Registration succeeded! Token: ", token)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Registration failed!")
}













func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

// Firebase notification received
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

   // let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary

 //  print(dict)

 //        let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
 //        let body : String = d["body"] as! String
 //        let title : String = d["title"] as! String

 //        
   //        print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
  //      
  //        
  //        
  //        self.showAlertAppDelegate(title:    title,message:body,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)


    completionHandler(.alert)


}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background


    if response.actionIdentifier == "goToApp"{

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nextViewController


    }else if response.actionIdentifier == "cancel" {

    print("close")

    }else {






    }



    print("Handle push from background or closed\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}

func showAlertAppDelegate(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
// Firebase ended here
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you are receiving notification in Android and having issue with iOS, then there is possibility that this issue comes because of Payload format. I also met with this issue earlier.

Please make sure that your Payload format must be like below.

```
{
    "aps" : {
      "alert" : {
        "body" : "great match!",
        "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      },
      "badge" : 1,
    },
    "customKey" : "customValue"
  }
```

And if your app running on ios 10 or later, then make sure you set `delegate`.

For more information, see [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55)

Comment: I've tried the following message: `{
    "data": {
        "aps" : {
      "alert" : {
          "body" : "great match!",
          "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
      },
      "badge" : 1
     },
     "customKey" : "customValue"
     },
     "to": "/topics/message"
}` However this still doesn't do anything. The delegates are set in the `requestNotificationAuthorization(application: UIApplication)` method.